# SQL Server won't perform regular expression validation on XML column

Tags: sql, xml, regex

I have an XML column in my table which contains this xsd snippet:

```
<xsd:element name="Postcode" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="^[0-9]{4}$" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

The regular expression should require a string containing 4 numerical digits.  It validates perfectly in Visual Studio and is a correct regular expression.

SQL Server, on the other hand, won't accept it.  The error message I receive is:

```
XML Validation: Invalid simple type value: '1234'. Location: / * : Donor[1]/*:Postcode[1].
```

I have an email address regex working fine, but can't get this simple numerical regex to work.

Answer (score 1):

Does your source XML look like this:

```
<Postcode>1234</Postcode>
```

or like this:

```
<Postcode>
    1234
</Postcode>
```

Since you are trimming the string (with `^` and `$`) make sure that your XML looks like the former and not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The XML Schema regex flavor doesn't support the start and end anchors; all matches are anchored at both ends, always.  It's probably trying to match '^' and '$' literally.

Comment: Yep - I've encountered this before. Removing the ^ and $ allowed the match to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no whitespace around the string.

I do have an email address regex which works perfectly.